# What is the max length for eSata and/or mini-SAS cables?

Tags: nas, cable, esata, specifications, sas

Does anybody know what is the maximum acceptable length for eSATA cables, and for mini-SAS cables?

I'm looking into buying a [RAID enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816111057&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-Server+-+RAID+Sub-Systems-_-SANS+DIGITAL-_-16111057) but I'd like to be able to keep it in a different room than my computer so I'd like to know how far away apart they can get - and also if it's feasible from the standpoint of being able to purchase such long cables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eSATA is [limited to 2 meters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Comparisons_with_other_interfaces). Mini-SAS is limited to 8 meters as is other SAS cable.

Answer (score 1):

6.6ft (2m) for ESATA is the max spec for length.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI (This has great pictures of all the connectors)

Yep, john is correct on the SAS, 8m.

Comment: "Mini-SAS (SFF-8088) x 2" taken from the NewEgg description.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Just learned about that myself now. Thanks. :)